# What table to put my foreign key in?

Tags: database-design

I have two entity relations called `Record_Label` and `Band`.
I currently have:

```
Record_label = /\ --- band (1:M)
               \/
```

Where the cardinality ratio is `1:M` and `record_label` has a total participation and `band` has partial participation.

I read on-line that when I have a many to partial participation, I put the table primary key from the partial `participation(band)` on to the many table (`record_label`).

But I also read that when it is `1:M` then I put the record_label primary key to the band table as a fk. My question is which one should I do?

Answer (score 3):

I'm gonna lose the theory for a minute and remind you that you're lacking a table. Bands don't have labels; record(ing)s do. A band can, throughout its career, publish recordings on many labels.

If, when Metallica left Megaforce to sign with Elektra, you simply changed the value in the 'label' foreign key column, you'd have no record (no pun intended) of the fact that they were ever with Megaforce. Actually, the albums Ride The Lightning and Kill 'Em All are what should be associated with the label Megaforce, while Master Of Puppets is associated with Elektra.

```
BandID: 
  pk in tblBand
  fk in tblAlbum

LabelID: 
  pk in tblLabel
  fk in tblAlbum
```

Comment: Thank you! I was not aware of that, then that means I would have a table called recordings with recordings(recording_id , recording_name).  Now then what are some examples of a recorder? Is it simply the studio that produced the song? & Also I belived that record labels signed a banned or artist to produce their music. So wouldnt just having two tables be enough and when they switch record labels you switch the record label id? & What about the theory part of the question? Any help on that would be appreciated thank you!